# What's wrong when my matrix is "not positive definite"?

Tags: java, math, matrix

i'm using the Jahmm java lib for classification. I want to do some testing so i generate some random data sets.

I create data sets in this format:

```
[val_1.1 val_1.2 val_1.3];[val_2.1 val_2.2 val_2.3]; [val_3.1 val_3.2 val_3.3] etc...
```

i use a random function so that

```
 val_1.1 == val_1.2 == val_1.3
```

and

```
val_2.1 == val_2.2 == val_2.3
```

and so on.

When i call the following function with this dataset it throws an    IllegalArgumentException

```
static double[][] decomposeCholesky(double[][] m)
{
    if (!isSquare(m))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix is not square");

    double[][] l = matrix(nbRows(m), nbColumns(m));

    for (int j = 0; j < nbRows(m); j++)
    {
        double[] lj = l[j];
        double d = 0.;

        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
            double[] lk = l[k];
            double s = 0.;

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                s += lk[i] * lj[i];

            lj[k] = s = (m[j][k] - s) / l[k][k];
            d = d + s * s;
        }

        if ((d = m[j][j] - d) <= 0.)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix is not positive " + 
            "defined");

        l[j][j] = Math.sqrt(d);
        for (int k = j+1; k < nbRows(m); k++)
            l[j][k] = 0.;
    }

    return l;
}
```

so my sequence matrix is not "positive defined", but what does it mean? And what should do to my dataset to avoid it?

I am not good in math! Thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix

Comment: Unrelated, but if you have some free time, study linear algebra, it will serve you, and it's "fun"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i do not know that library, 
but i think you mean "positive definite" not "positive defined".

here's the thing: if you have a normal number you can easily tell if it's positive oder negative (or zero) by looking at the sign. definiteness is an extension of that idea into the world of matrices, where just looking at the sign doesn't work anymore because some entries might be positive and some might be negative.

there are many different definitions of definiteness (which can proven to be equal), you can find them neatly listed here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations

now, the problem is that when you choose your rows equally that doesn't guarantee 
positive definiteness. in fact that 3x3 matrix will always be positive semidefinite and never positive definite.
i've looked around a bit; here are a few hints how to generate positive definite matrices: 
https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/04LinearAlgebra/posdef/

`( rand(n, n) + (n - 1)*eye( n ) )`

so you generate a n x n matrix where all entries are random between 0 and 1, 
then add the identity matrix multiplied with n-1, in your case that is [2,0,0];[0,2,0];...

hope that helps ...

---

p.s. i forgot your matrix has to be symmetric as well because you'd like to do a cholesky on it. but that's easy, just generate the matrix A as mentioned above, then choose B = 1/2 * ( A + A.transposed() ); 
This matrix B will still be positive definite and it'll be symmetric as well :)

Comment: +1 for the scalar-to-matrix analogy description of positive definite, and for practical suggestions on generating positive definite matrices.

Comment: I did find lots of articles on the internet explaining this in mathematical terms, as i said i'm not good at that (willing or unwillingly i dont know ;)) you're explanation is the first in plain english + a solution. thumbs up!

Answer (score 5):

I think the author of the code meant "positive definite."  A matrix must be positive definite in order to be factored with a Cholesky decomposition.  The formal definition is a square matrix A is positive definite if and only if, for all vectors x:

x'Ax > 0

All positive definite matrices are symmetric about the diagonal, and square, so a good start would be to use only square symmetric matrices in the test and see how that works. To absolutely ensure that a matrix is positive definite, you can test all its eigenvalues to see if they are each > 0.  I don't know if JAHMM has methods for taking the eigenvalues of a matrix but if so, you could do that.